# jwplayer video is not loaded on iOS devices at first visit

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, jwplayer

I have a website, which uses jwplayer.

When the visitor reaches the page first time, the video is not loaded. This issue can be seen, when entering https://www.omgyes.com/ first time on Iphone 6 (or other iOS device), and tap the play icon in hero section.

Everything starts working when page is refreshed once.

To see the issue, please open the page in incognito window, and tap play icon. Then refresh the page, and voila! it works!

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

When I go to your home page and tap the hero image, the player then loads on the page. After I tap the video play icon, the video plays. I did not have to refresh the page. I was looking on the iPhone 5.

Comment: please clear your cache, go incognito, and tap play icon in chrome